# Perl Ending loops/code blocks based on user input (!die/exit)

Tags: perl, exit, terminate, die

just have a general question that came up while I was playing around with some stuff I coded.  I was wondering if there is any way to terminate a specific part of the program based on user feedback (I apologize if I am misusing terminology here) other than die(); since that ends the entire program.

here's the code:

```
if ($choice eq 'y'){
print "\nHit diagnostics: \n";
{
my $hitList=@hitList;
for (my $i=0; $i<$hitList; $i++){
    print $hitList[$i]."\n";
    #segmented listout of misses with interrupt 
    if(($i%4) eq 0){
        print "CONTINUE or Q to end\n";
        my $next=<>;
        chomp($next);
        if(lc($next) eq 'q'){
            **die "Killing request...\n";**
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I just want for the user to be able to end the modulus if loop if they decide at some point that they don't actually want to see the entire list but still be able to continue (there is a miss prompt afterwards as well) with the program.

Is the best way to do this just to use a variable as a 'switch' to determine whether or not the hit list should continue? Just wondering if there is a more acceptable/elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for my $i (0..$hitList-1) {
   ...
   if (...) {
       last;
   }
   ...
}
```

[`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html)

Comment: (`last` works with "C-style" loops too. I just make the loop more readable when I copied it.)

Comment: If this answers your question, please close the question by checking the mark on the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: I would say "If this answer solved your problem, then please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark outline to its left."  That does signal no additional answers are needed, but it doesn't prevent people from adding them anyway if they think they have a better solution.  Closing a question does prevent additional answers.

Comment: @cjm, As you can see from my answers, I like saying *why*, not just *how*.